# tensorflow printing reshape results give inconsistent results

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to print an random tensor and tensor after flattening some of its dimentions. In the flattened tensor i am not able to see the same numbers as in the original tensor. Why is this behaviour showing up. Maybe i am not using tensorflow graphs the way it should be used. But this is pretty unintutive. What is happening behind the scenes in this case.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
tf.set_random_seed(1)
a_cC = tf.random_normal([1, 4, 4, 3], mean=1, stddev=4)
a_C_unrolled = tf.reshape(a_cC,[n_H*n_W,-1])
m, n_H, n_W, n_C = a_cC.get_shape().as_list()
#run the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op) #execute init_op
    #print the random values that we sample
    print (a_cC.eval())
    print(a_C_unrolled.eval())

[[[[ 5.21173716 -2.57399869  2.2410903 ]
   [ 5.91965914 -1.51706624  3.2767477 ]
   [-5.43970776  5.40671778 -2.23373938]
   [ 1.30087972 -3.63979769  4.04065228]]

  [[-0.60225141 -3.67490149 -2.65537524]
   [-0.46801746  8.29556847 -3.72800827]
   [ 3.0645113  -2.69916749  0.62769747]
   [-1.20489335  5.94129944 -3.44496584]]

  [[ 0.767515    3.72639561  3.76502395]
   [-2.08509254  0.56502891  4.45876408]
   [-4.26457405  2.33417678 -5.8700161 ]
   [ 1.68790722 -3.15862226  5.4228363 ]]

  [[-3.76462507  5.20460367  1.7311039 ]
   [ 5.35282135 -1.88765669  0.5600276 ]
   [ 7.26085281 -0.41734922 -3.47196579]
   [ 2.3799715   3.59994555 -5.574862  ]]]]
[[  4.17360973   2.97644758   1.60952783]
 [  2.36316919   4.27825832   0.35627228]
 [ -1.93402743  -0.77855718   1.19499707]
 [  9.27605629  -0.14986098  -4.86341763]
 [  2.68826199  -2.93058538   2.61971998]
 [ -3.33843374   8.2380991    2.73879862]
 [  2.23551083   8.69216537  -1.86058855]
 [ -0.06427336   4.50859356   1.98980188]
 [  1.19318628   1.28395951  -4.21570063]
 [ -3.17614985   4.91742516  10.99014568]
 [ -4.52236128   0.07621473  -4.08683443]
 [ -5.08178997  11.00571442  -1.07105398]
 [  2.51096773   4.26725626   7.13943052]
 [  2.7490077   -1.21482229   3.5335772 ]
 [  3.64062643   7.32875776   2.80212164]
 [  4.00615311   0.83125246  -3.00467968]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tensor doesn't maintain states, which is different from variable. [Variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables) can represent shared, persistent state. Therefore, every time you run an operation or evaluate a tensor, tensors(constants) in the graph start fresh. In your case, since your `a_cC` comes from `tf.random_normal`(without a fixed seed) and you evaluate `a_cC` and `a_C_unrolled` in two separated commands (`sess.run` or `.eval()`), underlying `a_cC`s will be different. To make this work the way you want, you will need to evaluate them in one single `sess.run`. Then their values will be consistent and "confirmed". Now you can print them out separately or together.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op) #execute init_op
    #print the random values that we sample
    a_cC_val, a_C_unrolled_val = sess.run((a_cC, a_C_unrolled))
    print(a_cC_val)
    print(a_C_unrolled_val)
```

## Edit for the `Variable` state

I believe the `Variable` state is not associated with the session. [Instead](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables),

> Internally, a tf.Variable stores a persistent tensor. Specific ops allow you to read and modify the values of this tensor. These modifications are ***visible across multiple tf.Sessions***, so multiple workers can see the same values for a tf.Variable.

## Edit for `eval()` vs `sess.run()`

As stated in [`tf.Tensor` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor)

> 2. After the graph has been launched in a session, the value of the Tensor can be computed by passing it to tf.Session.run. t.eval() is a shortcut for calling tf.get_default_session().run(t).

## Edit for random seed

First, as you may know, you will need to reset the seed in order to get the same number/sequence from consecutive calls.

Secondly, as explained in [`tf.set_random_seed` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed):

> Operations that rely on a random seed actually derive it from two seeds: the graph-level and operation-level seeds. This sets the graph-level seed.
>
> Its interactions with operation-level seeds is as follows:
>
> 1. If neither the graph-level nor the operation seed is set: A random seed is used for this op.
> 2. If the graph-level seed is set, but the operation seed is not: The system deterministically picks an operation seed in conjunction with the graph-level seed so that it gets a unique random sequence.
> 3. If the graph-level seed is not set, but the operation seed is set: A default graph-level seed and the specified operation seed are used to determine the random sequence.
> 4. If both the graph-level and the operation seed are set: Both seeds are used in conjunction to determine the random sequence.

Your case is #2. You do have the system deterministically picked an operation seed for you. But without a defined operation seed, your two consecutive calls give you two different things even though those two different things are always the same every time you run the whole code.

Put it together, I think you need to have the following to get consistent `a_cC` and `a_C_unrolled`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
tf.set_random_seed(1)
a_cC = tf.random_normal([1, 4, 4, 3], mean=1, stddev=4, seed=1)
n_H = 4
n_W = 4
a_C_unrolled = tf.reshape(a_cC,[n_H*n_W,-1])
m, n_H, n_W, n_C = a_cC.get_shape().as_list()
#run the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op) #execute init_op
    #print the random values that we sample
    print (a_cC.eval())
    a_cC = tf.random_normal([1, 4, 4, 3], mean=1, stddev=4, seed=1)
    a_C_unrolled = tf.reshape(a_cC,[n_H*n_W,-1])
    print(a_C_unrolled.eval())
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the state associated with the sess. Also what is the difference beteween eval() vs sess.run()? I have also set the tf.set_random_seed(1) at the beginning. Why is it not taking effect and generating same random numbers